# Where does doctype declaration go?

Tags: html, syntax, doctype

When I put `<!doctype html>` does it have to be at the top of my html and in that exact format?

However, in an assignment I'm doing I am required to use and not change html code, and I can only add css files, etc. In this html code, the structure is unique to anything I've ever seen where it looks something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <doctype html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" ...>
    <h1>...</h1>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

I understand what a doctype is and does and I always put them, but I'm wondering if that code is even valid or if the browser is ignoring the problems and just rendering it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the DOCTYPE declaration have to be the first tag in an HTML document?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69828/does-the-doctype-declaration-have-to-be-the-first-tag-in-an-html-document)

Comment: That's not even a valid DOCTYPE declaration. It should be at the top of the file, and it's missing the !. `<!DOCTYPE html>` You should just email your professor about this HTML... or just update it. That doctype tag will most-likely get ignored by the browser, though so it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like an extremely poorly-constructed assignment IMO, unless it was deliberate.

Comment: @BoltClock very true. I suppose it could be deliberate if it's in an education/assignment setting. I've never seen somebody get the doctype declaration this wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just really curious if it is actually valid. I think the assignment is well-constructed. The point isn't at all about html or even coding. It's a user experience class and is a quick refresher (or just fresher) for design students who don't speak any computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doctype declaration is invalid and will cause at least some browsers to go into weird compatibility modes.

W3c (at w3.org), on a page called [html5/syntax.html](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#syntax-doctype), says "a **DOCTYPE** is a required preamble" which I interpret to mean it is required and that it must come first.

It also says it must consist of the following components in this order:

1. A string that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the string `<!DOCTYPE`.
2. One or more space characters.
3. A string that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the string `html`.
4. Optionally, a DOCTYPE legacy string or an obsolete permitted DOCTYPE string.
5. Zero or more space characters.
6. A `>` (U+003E) character.

Answer (score 1):

Html declarations should go at the top of the file as it directs the web browser
that my HTML document is using which version.
HTML Tags depends on the web browser and the HTML version we are using.

Comment: Do you have a source that says it must go at the top?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/Doctype this says markup validator tool uses this doctype to check the syntax of HTML so according to me its necessary to put it at the top to allow complete syntax checking

Answer (score 1):

That DOCTYPE declaration isn't properly written or in the correct location valid per this [informative but dated article](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/primers/html/article.php/3701321/Using-the-DOCTYPE-Tag.htm). It's actually an HTML comment, not a tag.

> The `<DOCTYPE>` declaration must be the very first thing in your
>   document, before the `<html>` tag.

It should be `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of the file above the html tag.

---

As far as how it's handled,

Modern browsers have a [quirks-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode), where they attempt to interpret improperly written HTML. I'm not exactly sure how each browser would handle that tag, but it is definitely cause for concern:

1. The tag isn't closed. So it's likely going to wrap all the content inside of the body, which would lead to some unexpected CSS issues.
2. Or the doctype tag would be ignored completely (this is probably just wishful thinking)

A quick test, shows that the tag is handled in a weird way. It's wrapping the other content.. kind of? Eh. Weird:

http://jsfiddle.net/CoryDanielson/6d12grLg/

Answer (score 1):

The doctype string needs to be at the start to have any effect. Its *only* effect on browsers is to affect the choice of browser mode, namely “standards”, “almost standards”, or “quirks” mode. When there is no doctype string at the start, [quirks mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html) is selected. This has considerable implications on the use of CSS. So if this is an assignment, they are either playing tricks on you, or incompetent.

It is irrelevant what the specifications say (and this is covered in answers to older questions at SO). If you are required to use HTML as in the question, the code is invalid anyway on several grounds (lack of doctype string, lack of `title` element, invalid `<doctype html>` tag, and `link` element placed inside `body`). Yet, the code works, for some values of “work”, but in quirks mode.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML `<!DOCTYPE>` Declaration**

***Definition and Usage***

The `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration must be the very first thing in your HTML document, before the `<html>` tag.

The `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration is not an HTML tag; it is an instruction to the web browser about what version of HTML the page is written in.

In HTML 4.01, the `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration refers to a DTD, because HTML 4.01 was based on SGML. The DTD specifies the rules for the markup language, so that the browsers render the content correctly.

HTML5 is not based on SGML, and therefore does not require a reference to a DTD.

*Tip: Always add the `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration to your HTML documents, so that the browser knows what type of document to expect.*

Source:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

**W3C:**

http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/Doctype

Comment: Can you add a link or source? And a good deal of that is irrelevant info.

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted for the quick answer and the statement, but I have beefs with w3schools.com and I'm really looking for a definitive answer to "is that doctype declaration valid", so I won't accept this answer as the correct one.

Comment: I have updated my answer with W3C links.. it might be reliable for you.

Comment: Do you know that every one of the statements quoted from w3schools is slightly incorrect.