# What does adding a random character in front of <!DOCTYPE html> do in index.html?

Tags: html, web-applications

In a javascript web app what would adding a random character in front of  in the index.html file do?

For example:

```
s<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     .
     .
     .
</html>
```

I have a pretty big app that works when that random character is there and doesn't work when it's not. It's driving me crazy.

Comment: I don't understand. You're asking what would happen if the character were there... then answering your own question by stating that things don't work. What you should be investing is *why* the character is there.

Comment: Completely agreed, but things do work. I'm trying to figure out what that would do to the HTML's syntax integrity.

Comment: quirks mode was the answer i was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you [validate](https://html5.validator.nu/) this HTML, you’ll see several errors. If you read [`document.compatMode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/compatMode), it changes to `"BackCompat"`. As [`<!DOCTYPE html>` must be the first tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69828/4642212) in an HTML document in order for it be valid, a character before it causes `<!DOCTYPE html>` to be considered a *stray* tag, rather than a proper document type declaration.

This enables [**quirks mode**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode) as opposed to standards mode. Your app breaks due to relying on [any of these quirks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mozilla_quirks_mode_behavior).